# How to add tooltips to a Box plot in TeeChart?

Tags: c#, teechart

As the title says, I am using TeeChart to draw several boxplots within one chart object. Since, the number of boxplots can be quite big, I want to be able to click on a box and have information pertaining to that series to show up as a tooltip.

I am currently trying to do this with a MarksTip but for some reason, when I try to hover over the box, MarksTip will sometimes open and then immediately close (basically being visible for a split second). I have already tried setting the hide delay but it seems to be ignoring that.

Code snippet below:

```
seriesIndex = 0;

foreach (var seriesData in seriesDataList)
{
    var series = new Box()

    series.UseCustomValues = true;
    series.Box.HorizSize = 5;
    series.Box.Style = PointerStyles.Rectangle;
    series.MildOut.Visible = true;
    series.MildOut.HorizSize = 2;
    series.MildOut.VertSize = 2;
    series.ExtrOut.Visible = true;
    series.ExtrOut.HorizSize = 2;
    series.ExtrOut.VertSize = 2;
    series.LinePen.Visible = _isLineVisible;
    series.Pointer.Pen.Visible = true;
    series.ShowInLegend = false;

    series.Add(seriesIndex, seriesData);

    series.Title = "tooltip text";
    var tooltip = new MarksTip(Chart.Chart)
    {
        Series = series,
        Style = MarksStyles.SeriesTitle,
        HideDelay = 31000,
    };
    Chart.Series.Add(series);

    seriesIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28040979/3597806) for pointing me in the right direction.

I ended up using the `GetSeriesMark` event to modify the text of a single chart-bound `MarksTip` instead of creating multiple series-bound `MarksTip

```
seriesIndex = 0;
Chart.Tools.Add(new MarksTip());

foreach (var seriesData in seriesDataList)
{
    var series = new Box()

    series.UseCustomValues = true;
    //Other series appearance stuff

    series.Add(seriesIndex, seriesData);

    series.Title = "tooltip text";
    series.GetSeriesMark += (s, args) =>
    {
        args.MarkText = s.Title;
    };
    series.Marks.Visible = false;
    Chart.Series.Add(series);    
    seriesIndex++;
}
```

One note about this method. The tooltip will only appear when hovering over actual datapoints and not the whole box. Not ideal but at least I can read the tooltip now.